# ¿Cómo agregar declaración a objeto XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml, xpath

Desarrollo una aplicación donde creo un objeto XmlDocument  a partir de una clase.

En mi codigo tengo lo siguiente:
       a) Una clase donde declaro atributos y propiedades, 
       b) Un método donde establezco los valores de estas propiedades 
       c) Un método donde serializo y creo el objeto XmlDocument a partir de     los puntos a y b

El problema es que mi declaracion se ve de la siguiente forma

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

Deberia verse de la siguiente forma

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

¿Dónde y cómo puedo hacer para establecer el tipo de codificación del objeto XmlDocument?

Mi Clase :

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class FacturaElectronica {

    private string claveField;

    private string numeroConsecutivoField;

    public string Clave {
        get {
            return this.claveField;
        }
        set {
            this.claveField = value;
        }
    }

    public string NumeroConsecutivo {
        get {
            return this.numeroConsecutivoField;
        }
        set {
            this.numeroConsecutivoField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

b) Metodo donde establesco valores de las propiedades:

```
  public FacturaElectronica CrearEstructuraFactura()
        {
            FacturaElectronica FacturaElectronica = new FacturaElectronica()
            {
                Clave = value.Clave,
                NumeroConsecutivo = value.NumeroConsecutivo
            }
         return FacturaElectronica;
      }
```

c) Metodo donde serializo y creo el XmlDocument

```
public XmlDocument  CrearDocumentoXml( ComprobanteElectronicoCRI objComprobanteElectronicoCRI, string tipoDocumento)
        { 
            XmlDocument documentoXml = new XmlDocument();
           CreadorFactura XmlFactura = new CreadorFactura();
           FacturaElectronica FacturaElectronica = new FacturaElectronica();
           FacturaElectronica = XmlFactura.CrearEstructuraFactura(objComprobanteElectronicoCRI);
           var nav = documentoXml.CreateNavigator();
           using (writer = nav.AppendChild())
           {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FacturaElectronica));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, FacturaElectronica);
           }

            return documentoXml; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe declarar una variable de tipo XmlDeclaration  y pasar los parametros como lo son version y codificacion para el xml ,despues de crear el objeto XmlDocument

en mi caso lo hize donde serializo y creo el XmlDocument

El codigo quedo asi:

```
public XmlDocument  CrearDocumentoXml( ComprobanteElectronicoCRI objComprobanteElectronicoCRI, string tipoDocumento)
        { 
            XmlDocument documentoXml = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaracion = documentoXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
           XmlElement root = documentoXml.DocumentElement;
           documentoXml.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaracion, root);
           CreadorFactura XmlFactura = new CreadorFactura();
           FacturaElectronica FacturaElectronica = new FacturaElectronica();
           FacturaElectronica = XmlFactura.CrearEstructuraFactura(objComprobanteElectronicoCRI);
           var nav = documentoXml.CreateNavigator();
           using (writer = nav.AppendChild())
           {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FacturaElectronica));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, FacturaElectronica);
           }

            return documentoXml; 
        }
```